# Show function involving Grassmannian is surjective

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, grassmannian

Let $\text{SO}_n$ denote the special orthogonal group and $G(n,k)$ be the set of all $k$-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $f:\text{SO}_n\to G(n,k)$ given by $f(O)=OL$, where $O\in \text{SO}_n$ and $L\in G(n,k)$ ($L$ is fixed) is surjective.

I'm not really sure how to show this and could use some help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that you can rotate any $k$-dimensional subspace to any other. Pick a basis $B$ of subspace $L_1,$ complete it to a basis $\mathbf{B}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Now pick a basis $C$ of $L_2,$ complete it to a basis $\mathbf{C}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Now, find an orthogonal transformation sending $\mathbf{B}$ to $\mathbf{C}.$

Comment: Minor point:  All the occurrences of "basis" should be "orthonormal basis".  Otherwise there may may not be an orthogonal transformation sending $\mathbf{B}$ to $\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, indeed. I assumed it was obvious from context :)